# How to have same values in dropdown - flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a list of map for holding product name along with its value. For example: Let's assume that there are two types of products (kitchen and electronic) and both products hold the same value (10)

In such case, the dropdown would throw the following error: Either zero or 2 or more were detected with the same value

So how can I have same value for dropdown in such circumstances

here is what I have done so far

```
String productCategory = '10';
List productList = [{'name':'kitchen', 'value':'10'}, {'name':'electronic', 'value':'10'}];

DropdownButton(
                                  value: productCategory,
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  items: productList.map((e){
                                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                                      child: Text(e['name'].toString().toUpperCase(), style: GoogleFonts.oswald(textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
                                      value: e['value'],
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (value){
                                    setState(() {
                                      productCategory = value as String;
                                    });
                                  }
                              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be creating DropdownButton of type Product

```
late List<Product> products;
List productList = [
{'name': 'kitchen', 'value': '10'},
{'name': 'electronic', 'value': '10'}];

 @override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   products = productList.map((e) => Product.fromJson(e)).toList();
   productCategory = products.first;
  }

DropdownButton<Product>(
        value: productCategory,
        isExpanded: true,
        items: products.map((e) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(e.name.toString().toUpperCase()),
            value: e,
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            productCategory = value!;
          });
        }),


class Product {
 final String name;
 final String value;

 Product({required this.name, required this.value});

 factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      name: json['name'],
      value: json['value']);
   }
}
```

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: So basically you’re suggesting me to use list of objects instead of maps, right? How would that make difference?

Comment: As per my knowledge we cannot pass same values to dropdown, so Instead of passing a String value for dropdown which have same value  you can pass object. This also helps you to identified which product is selected.

Comment: Understood! Basically I should assign object to drop down value instead of passing string value! Later I can access the value from object

Comment: Yes, if you find this helpful please upvote